# How to convert <class bytes> to array or string in python?

Tags: python-3.x

`subprocess.popen` is returning the output as class bytes as below

> b'Caption  FreeSpace     Size           \r\r\nC:       807194624
>   63869808640    \r\r\nD:                                    \r\r\nY:
>   216847310848  2748779065344  \r\r\n\r\r\n'

How to remove all occurance of `\r\r\n` Or how can I convert this to python string or array

Answer (score 2):

```
my_str = "hello world"
```

## Converting string to bytes

```
my_str_as_bytes = str.encode(my_str)
```

## Converting bytes to string

```
my_decoded_str = my_str_as_bytes.decode()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print it by:

```
print(b'Caption FreeSpace ... \r\r\n\r\r\n'.decode())
```

Result:

```
Caption FreeSpace ...
```

Comment: Also with string = XXX.decode() you can convert it to string and treat it as a string, such as split or anything

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the characters with [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.translate) like so

```
b'Caption FreeSpace ... \r\r\n\r\r\n'.translate(None, b'\r\n')
```

which results in

```
b'Caption FreeSpace Size C: 807194624 63869808640 D: Y: 216847310848 2748779065344 '
```

If you know the encoding of the returned data you may want to use [decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) which will give you a string for further processing.
For example, assumed it is encoded in utf-8, you can just call `decode` with its default value and directly call `split` on it to split by white-space characters to get an array like this

```
b'Caption FreeSpace ... \r\r\n\r\r\n'.translate(None, b'\r\n').decode().split()
```

Result

```
['Caption', 'FreeSpace', 'Size', 'C:', '807194624', '63869808640', 'D:', 'Y:', '216847310848', '2748779065344']
```

Comment: Thanks for info. When the type is < class list>.then how can i replace all \r\n. Because when i apply decode it says .testresult is <class 'list'> type
Encountered exception during remote execution 
    print (testresult.decode())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Sry for late reply ... Can you show a bit more of your code so that I can see how testresult is being filled/set?